# The cardinality of $A$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A = \{ x/y  : x/y \lt 1 \ ,\  y \lt 13  \ ,\  x , y \in \mathbb{N}\}$ . Find the  value of $|A|$ . I wrote all the possibilities for $x$ and $y$ and then removed duplicate values . For example $1/2$ , $2 / 4$ are the same . It took a long time for writing them . I'm looking for another way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The totient $\phi (n),$ for $n \in \Bbb N,$ is the number of values of  $m\in \Bbb N $ for which $1\leq m\leq n$ and  $\gcd (m,n)=1.$ If $x\in A$ then there are unique $m,n\in \Bbb N$ with $m<n\leq 12$ and $\gcd (m,n)=1$ and $m/n=x.$ So the number of members of $A$ is $$\sum_{n=2}^{12}\phi (n).$$ If $n$ is prime then $\phi (n)=n-1.$ More generally, if $n$ is prime and $k\in \Bbb N$ then $\phi (n^k)=n^{k-1}(n-1).$ And if $a,b\in \Bbb N$ and $\gcd (a,b)=1$ then $\phi (ab)=\phi (a)\phi (b).$

$$(\phi (2),\phi (4),\phi (8))=(1,2,4).$$  $$(\phi (3),\phi (9))=(2,6).$$  $$(\phi (5),\phi (7), \phi (11))=(4,6,10).$$  $$(\phi (6),\phi (10), \phi (12))=(\phi (2 )\phi (3),\phi (2)\phi (5).\phi (4)\phi (3))=$$ $$=(1\cdot 2, 1\cdot 4,2\cdot 2)=(2,4,4).$$

Comment: My Answer is $45$ . Is that right ?

Comment: Yes indeed.  BTW if you replace "$13$'' in your Q with some general value $M\in \Bbb N ,$ the value of $f(M)=\sum_{n=2}^{M-1}\phi (n)$ will depend strongly on the distribution of primes less than $M,$ so  I don't expect that there is a simple  exact formula for $f(M) $.

Comment: Really fantastic answer . Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can start with the set

$A=\{\frac{x}{y}:y<13 , x ,y\in \mathbb{N}\}$, and remove all duplicates. Then, remove all the examples with equal numerator and denominator. I think that then, the number that you want will be half of the total remaining.

Comment: Can you explain more ?